# Default path in AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

We have an Rest API config in AWS API gateway where we want to route to handle a default path

```
/
 /api
 /$default (default path here)
```

**Note** we are not looking for the greedy path {proxy+}

```
/ 
 /api
 /{proxy+}
```

the problem with the  greedy path is no request will route to /api ...always the {proxy+}
will take precedence even though the request has /api (tried it out)

Any help from the community in pointing us in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to this problem. I'm trying to use /service1/{proxy} admin/service1/{proxy to route to the same function. I have a routing inside the lambda but AWS cuts out both the /service1 and /admin/service1 from the route so it always returns 404 cos I need the full route to be available. I'm not sure what the thought was behind this behavior cos I don't think it makes any sense. Removing the ${proxy} forwards the full route as it should

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$default` route to catche requests that don't explicitly match other routes in your API.

When the `$default` route receives a request, API Gateway sends the full request path to the integration. For example, you can create an API with only a $default route and integrate it on the ANY method with the `https://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com` HTTP endpoint.

When you send a request to `https://api-id.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/store/checkout`, API Gateway sends a request to `https://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/store/checkout`.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html).

Comment: i have already tried the $default path which i have specified in the question ...in the documentation there is no way to show how to configure the path